# Simplifying Differentiation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working off my textbook and I've followed the steps easily enough until it gets to this

> $ \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac{(x^2 + 1)^3}{2 \sqrt{x - 1}} + \sqrt{x-1}~(6x)~(x^2 + 1)^2$
>
> $= \dfrac{(x^2 + 1)^2}{2\sqrt{x - 1})}[(x^2 + 1) + 12x(x - 1)]$
>
> $= \dfrac{(x^2 + 1)^2(13x^2 - 12x + 1)}{2\sqrt{x - 1}}$

How do they go from the first line onwards?

Thanks in advance (sorry about formatting)

Comment: It really help readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). I started this one off for you in the hopes that you can complete it. Regards

Comment: Oh, thanks for that, will remember for later :D

Comment: Please make sure I got edits correct. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that we are looking at
$$\frac{(x^2+1)^3}{2\sqrt{x-1}} +\sqrt{x-1}(6x)(x^2+1)^2.$$
Take out the common factor $(x^2+1)^2$, and multiply and divide by $2\sqrt{x-1}$. We get
$$\frac{(x^2+1)^2}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\left((x^2+1)+(2)(x+1)(6x)     \right).$$
Now simplify the expression on the right.

That seems to be the way it was thought of. I would prefer to first bring the expression to the common denominator $2\sqrt{x-1}$. We then get 
$$\frac{(x^2+1)^3 +2(x-1)(6x)(x^2+1)^2}{2\sqrt{x-1}}.$$
Now take out the common factor 
$\dfrac{(x^2+1)^2}{2\sqrt{x-1}}$. Perhaps that was the way it was done, with a step skipped.

**Remark:** If you have seen the (natural) logarithm already, the following approach, called *logarithmic differentiation*, may appeal to you. It is of at most marginal utility in this problem, but could be useful when differentiating a longer product.

We were differentiating $(x^2+1)^3 \sqrt{x-1}$. Let
$$y=(x^2+1)^3\sqrt{x-1}.$$
Take the natural logarithm of both sides. Using "laws of logarithms," we get
$$\ln y=3\ln(x^2+1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-1).$$
Differentiate, using the Chain Rule. We get
$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6x}{x^2+1} +\frac{1}{2(x-1)}.$$
Finally, multiply by $y$ to get $\frac{dy}{dx}$.